# Python Tkinter rotate image already on display with press of a button

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I am trying to rotate an image on Tkinter window while it is on display with the press of a button. I tried to make it in the code seen below. When I try that code image on the directory gets rotated but the image on display stays the same. Can anyone help me with this?

Here is the last thing I tried:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import cv2
import numpy as np

global rotater
rotater=True
def rotate_img(img_path, rt_degr):
    img = Image.open(img_path)
    return img.rotate(rt_degr, expand=1)

def draw():
    global rotater

    if rotater:
        img_rt_90 = rotate_img("sas.png", 90)
        img_rt_90.save("sas.png")
        label.config(image=image)
        rotater = False
    else:
        img_rt_90 = rotate_img("sas.png", 90)
        img_rt_90.save("sas.png")
        label.config(image=image)
        rotater = True
root = Tk()
image = cv2.imread("sas.png")
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
image = Image.fromarray(image)
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label = Label(image=image)
label.pack()
but12=Button(root,text="deneme",command=draw)
but12.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you assigned old image to label inside `draw()`:

```
def draw():
    global rotater

    if rotater:
        img_rt_90 = rotate_img("sas.png", 90)
        img_rt_90.save("sas.png")
        label.config(image=image) # <- assigned original image
        rotater = False
    else:
        img_rt_90 = rotate_img("sas.png", 90)
        img_rt_90.save("sas.png")
        label.config(image=image) # <- assigned original image
        rotater = True
```

You need to assign the rotated image as below:

```
def draw():
    global rotater, image # use global "image"

    if rotater:
        img_rt_90 = rotate_img("sas.png", 90)
        img_rt_90.save("sas.png")
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_rt_90) # update image with rotated one
        label.config(image=image)
        rotater = False
    else:
        img_rt_90 = rotate_img("sas.png", 90)
        img_rt_90.save("sas.png")
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_rt_90) # update image with rotated one
        label.config(image=image)
        rotater = True
```

*The content in the `if` and `else` block are basically the same, why?*

Comment: Thank you so so much for your answer ! You helped me a lot !